# How to use A, S, D, W keys in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm using **[Phaser.io](http://phaser.io/)**

I would like to use `A`,`S`,`D`,`W` keys. I know that you can use arrow keys like this:

```
create(){
  ...
  gameState.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

update(){
  if (gameState.cursors.left.isDown) {
    gameState.player1.setVelocityX(-160);
  } else if (gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
    gameState.player1.setVelocityX(160);
  }
}
```

I tried to switch `.left.` for `.A.` and `.right.` for `.D.` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Phaser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Phaser 3.19.0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found a solution:

- **First**, declare the variable that will hold the future keys:

```
let keyA;
let keyS;
let keyD;
let keyW;
```

- **Second**, in the **`create()`** function, add the keys to the corresponding variables:

```
keyA = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A);
keyS = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S);
keyD = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D);
keyW = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W);
```

- **Third**, let's try to press the keys now to see if they work. In the **`update()`** function, add the following **code snippet**:

```
if(keyA.isDown) {
   console.log('A key pressed')
} else if(keyS.isDown) {
   console.log('S key pressed')
} else if(keyD.isDown) {
   console.log('D key pressed')
} else if(keyW.isDown) {
   console.log('W key pressed')
}
```

You can press each individual key & check the `console` message to see if it gets print.

To get the ***list of all keyboard key codes*** for future reference:

```
console.log(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `Phaser.KeyCode.A` to detect normal keyboard characters. Have a look at  to see all the key codes.

[Phaser 2.4.4 - Phaser.KeyCode](https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.KeyCode.html)

Update:

[Phaser 3 - Phaser.input.Keyboard.KeyCodes](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.html)

Comment: These are the Phaser 2 docs. OP said they were using Phaser 3.19

Comment: They are extremely different, it’s almost a completely different framework. I take it you haven’t used Phaser before?

Comment: @exciteabletom nope. I just searched it up.